# for what values of $n$ ,$n^4+4$ is composite number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

for what values of $n$ ,$n^4+4$ is composite number?

$n^4+4=a.b\Rightarrow (n^2-2n+2)(n^2+2n+2)=ab$

what to conclude next?
Thank you

Comment: Well, if both factors are $> 1$, it's composite. So it can only be non-composite if one of the factors is $1$, that is...

Comment: you just have to check for what values of $n$ you have $n^2-2n+2=1$ or $n^2+2n+2=1$

Comment: @DanielFischer +1 :)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632615/the-number-n4-4-is-never-prime-for-n1 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121407/show-that-n44-is-not-a-prime-number

Answer (score 1):

Let's set the factors equal to $1$: $$n^2 - 2n + 2 = 1 \implies n^2 - 2n + 1 = 0 \implies n = 1$$

Similarly, $$n^2 + 2n + 2 = 1 \implies n^2 + 2n + 1 = 0 \implies n = -1$$

We can check and see that when $n = \pm 1$, the value of $n^4 + 4$ is indeed prime. Hence, for any other $n$, namely $n \neq \pm 1$, this will be composite.