# The number $n^4 + 4$ is never prime for $n>1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am taking a basic algebra course, and one of the proposed problems asks to prove that  $n^4 + 4$ is never a prime number for $n>1$.

I am able to prove it in some particular cases, but I am not able to do it when $n$ is an odd multiple of $5$.

Comment: If $n$ is an even multiple of $5$, $n$ is a multiple of $10$ so $n^4 + 4$ is even.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121407/show-that-n44-is-not-a-prime-number and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581764/for-what-values-of-n-n44-is-composite-number

Answer (score 7):

$n^4 + 4 = (2 - 2 n + n^2) (2 + 2 n + n^2)$

Comment: @D3roX4: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ $ Completing the square leads to a difference of squares

$$\begin{eqnarray} &&\ \, n^4 + 2^2\\ \,&=&\, (n^2\!+2)^2\!-(2n)^2\\ \,&=&\, (n^2\!+2\ -\ 2n)\ (n^2\!+2\ +\ 2n)\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 0):

More generalized: $a^4 + 4b^4 = a^4 + 4a^2b^2 + 4b^4 - 4a^2b^2 = (a^2 + 2b^2)^2 - (2ab)^2 = (a^2+2b^2-2ab)(a^2+2b^2+2ab)$