# How to find a polynomial product that give me $x^6+1$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

I need to find a polynomials product that give me $x^6+1$ at $\mathbb{R}[X]$ and at $\mathbb{C}[X]$.

I need that the product will be of irreducible polynumials...

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may like $$\begin{align}x^6+1&=(x^2+1)(x^4-x^2+1)\\&=(x^2+1)(x^2+\sqrt 3x+1)(x^2-\sqrt 3x+1)\\&=(x+i)(x-i)(x^2+\sqrt 3x+1)(x^2-\sqrt 3x+1).\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! but how do you get this? can you explain me the way please? And waht about $\mathbb{C}[X]$? can you help me with this? Thank you!!

Comment: You can use $(x^2)^3+1.$ Also, $x^4-x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-3x^2.$ Also, $x^2+1=(x+i)(x-i).$

Comment: It helps to recognize that $x^6$ is both a square and a cube.  The first line comes from the sum of cubes formula.

Comment: @Yoav [Completing the square](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/632645/242) results in a difference of squares, hence a factorization
$$\ x^4\! + b^2 - ax^2 = (x^2\!+b)^2\!-(2b\!+\!a)\,x^2 = (x^2+b)^2-(\sqrt{2b+a}\ x)^2$$

Comment: @mathlove, I add something to the question...

Comment: @mathlove, I need to find the product at $\mathbb{R}$ and then, begin from the beginning at $\mathbb{C}$.... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact every complex root of Polynomials with real coefficients comes with its conjugate.

Then you can find the roots of 1 by using:

$e^{\pi+2ki}=-1$ for all integers k and ${e^{\pi}} ^{1/6}=e^{\pi/6+1/3 k\pi i}$

Comment: You can help me with this? How do I get from this a irreducible polynumial?

Comment: Using Fundamental theorem of Algebra you know that every polynomial of order n has n roots (with multiplicity) in  $\mathbb{C}[X]$ so you know you can divide that polynomial in a multiplication of 6 monoms, each of the form $(x-x_0)$ as shown in the comments above after having found $(x^2+1)$ you do common polynomial division and the use formula for solving polynomials of the form $a{x^d}^2+bx^d+c=0$
At last you go back to $\mathbb{R}[X]$ by combining the conjugate complex roots

Comment: Yes, but it different section, I need to find all of them at $\mathbb{C}$... At the comment above is good for $\mathbb{R}$. Thank you!!!

Comment: How do I use the $e^{...}$ method to find the polynomials, this what I meant :-).