# How can I find a root number that when added up with a certain number will be equal to a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, exponentiation

I have a problem to solve, which looks like this:
$$a^4+4=b$$

$a$ is a natural number where when it is multiplied by the exponent, it'll  be equal to $b$

$b$ is always a **prime number**

We have to find what number is $a$

First off, every time $a$ is multiplied by the exponent and added by 4, it'll always be an even number no matter what. The problem said that the set for the problem will at least have one number, but I couldn't seem to think of a way it can be so. Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Note: I wrote down "root number" on the title of the post, which means something other than I meant. What I actually meant is what number that when has the exponent of 4, will be equal to a prime number when added to four.

Comment: Look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1121407/show-that-n44-is-not-a-prime-number

Comment: Why (and where) are you multiplying by the exponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a>1$ , $b $ cannot be prime because $a^4 + 4 = (a^2 + 2 + 2a)(a^2+2-2a)$

Note: This is a special case of Sophie German identity which gives factors of $a^4 + 4 c^4$

Comment: When $a=1$ it is prime because $(a^2+2-2a)=1$

Comment: Took me a while to notice it, I didn't really catch on the problem and now it all seems obvious. It's always the case when the exponent is even.